# Angular custom mat chip color

Tags: angular

Is there any way to make the mat chip to have a custom color other than the primary, accent, warn and default? This is my code now:

```html
<mat-chip *ngIf="status.name==='open'" color="warn" selected trans>{{status.display_name}}</mat-chip>
<mat-chip *ngIf="status.name==='pending'" color="accent" selected trans>{{status.display_name}}</mat-chip>
<mat-chip *ngIf="status.name==='assigned'" color="primary" selected trans>{{status.display_name}}</mat-chip>
<mat-chip *ngIf="status.name==='verification'" color="yellow" selected trans>{{status.display_name}}</mat-chip>
```

And yeah it's pretty obvious I want the last mat-chip to have a yellow color to it. The color='primary' is black now and I want to change it to be green but I have no idea how to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please check [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11888#issuecomment-536509515)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add CSS class instead of `color="primary"`
Create you own CSS class

```
.assigned-chip{
     background-color: <<color code>> // as per your requirement
}

<mat-chip *ngIf="status.name==='assigned'" class="assigned-chip">{{status.display_name}}</mat-chip>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me crazy since i had no experience with angular. i've tried your method and it wasnt working because of the selected trans. Removing it allowed me to use custom classes now.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution for your problem. I'm using Angular 13, and with `[ngStyle]` you can change the value of a CSS property, even you can insert a value from your TS file component. I know this is not correct, because the CSS code should be written in a style file, but sometimes if we do an exception the problem can be solved. I hope this can help someone, maybe there's a better solution, but it work for me.

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of tags" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': colorTags[tag]}">
  {{tag}}
</mat-chip>
```